# Sonar not showing violation using custom rules?

Tags: java, php, typo3, sonarqube, phpcodesniffer

I am trying to integrate Sonar for code review and analysis . I am working in typo3, so I  added the following rules in `rules.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <rules>

    <rule key="TYPO3.Commenting.FunctionDocComment.TagIndenst"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>Tag comment incorrectly indented</name>
        <configKey>TAG_INDENT</configKey>
        <description>@category tag comment incorrectly indented</description>
    </rule>

    <rule
        key="TYPO3.Commenting.NoAuthorAnnotationInFunctionDocComment.AuthorAnnotation"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>NoAuthorAnnotationInFunctionDocComment</name>
        <configKey>TAG_INDENT</configKey>
        <description>@category tag comment incorrectly indented</description>
    </rule>



    <rule key="TYPO3.Commenting.ValidCommentIndent.ValidCommentIndent"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>ValidCommentIndent</name>
        <configKey>T_COMMENT</configKey>
        <description>@category tag comment incorrectly indented</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.Commenting.ValidCommentLineLength.ValidCommentLineLength"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>ValidCommentLineLength</name>
        <configKey>T_COMMENT, T_DOC_COMMENT</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.Commenting.ValidCommentLineLength.ValidCommentLineLength"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>ValidCommentLineLength</name>
        <configKey>T_COMMENT, T_DOC_COMMENT</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.ControlStructures.AlignedBreakStatement.AlignedBreakStatement"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>AlignedBreakStatement</name>
        <configKey>T_BREAK,</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.ControlStructures.DisallowEachInLoopCondition.DisallowEachInLoopCondition"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>DisallowEachInLoopCondition</name>
        <configKey>T_WHILE,</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.ControlStructures.DisallowElseIfConstruct.DisallowElseIfConstruct"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>DisallowElseIfConstruct</name>
        <configKey>T_WHILE,</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.ControlStructures.ValidBreakStatementsInSwitches.ValidBreakStatementsInSwitches"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>ValidBreakStatementsInSwitches</name>
        <configKey>T_BREAK,</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.ControlStructures.ValidDefaultStatementsInSwitches.ValidDefaultStatementsInSwitches"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>ValidDefaultStatementsInSwitches</name>
        <configKey>T_SWITCH,</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>
    <rule key="TYPO3.Debug.DebugCode.DebugCode"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>DebugCode</name>
        <configKey>T_STRING, T_COMMENT,</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.Files.EncodingUtf8.EncodingUtf8"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>EncodingUtf8</name>
        <configKey>T_OPEN_TAG</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.Files.IncludingFile.IncludingFile"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>IncludingFile</name>
        <configKey>T_INCLUDE_ONCE, T_REQUIRE, T_INCLUDE</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.Files.LowercasedFilename.LowercasedFilename"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>LowercasedFilename</name>
        <configKey>T_OPEN_TAG</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.Files.OneClassPerFile.OneClassPerFile"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>OneClassPerFile</name>
        <configKey>T_CLASS</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.Files.OneInterfacePerFile.OneInterfacePerFile"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>OneInterfacePerFile</name>
        <configKey>T_INTERFACE</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.NamingConventions.ValidFunctionName.ValidFunctionName"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>ValidFunctionName</name>
        <configKey>T_FUNCTION</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>
    <rule key="TYPO3.NamingConventions.ValidVariableName.ValidVariableName"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>ValidVariableName</name>
        <configKey></configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.PHP.CharacterAfterPHPClosingTag.CharacterAfterPHPClosingTag"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>CharacterAfterPHPClosingTag</name>
        <configKey>T_CLOSE_TAG</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>

    <rule key="TYPO3.PHP.CharacterBeforePHPOpeningTag.CharacterBeforePHPOpeningTag"
        priority="MAJOR">
        <category name="Maintainability" />
        <name>CharacterBeforePHPOpeningTag</name>
        <configKey>T_OPEN_TAG</configKey>
        <description>@category</description>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

When the code analysis i am not able to get any kind of violations , Please help ???

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you followed the guidelines that explain how to add new rules to Sonar rule repository: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+PHP+Coding+Rules#ExtendingPHPCodingRules-ExtendingPHPCodesnifferRules

But you probably haven't added those new rules to the quality profile that you are using. This is why you get no violation. Have a look at this page to understand how to handle quality profiles in Sonar: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles

Comment: @Fabric-Sonar Team:  Yes i have only enabled those rules which added by mean . See what am trying is to develop a review system with sonar , Which can review typo3 projects . when i check this /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/.sonar/target/logs/codesniffer.xml there i can see the violations . But not in the dashboard ..

Comment: OK i have removed the same , and restarted sonar . But no violations for me . when i checked log its shows something like this 
2013.01.18 14:47:14 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [phppmd_rules/php] done: 129 ms
2013.01.18 14:47:14 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Register rules [php_codesniffer_rules/php]...
2013.01.18 14:47:14 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  607 rules

Comment: Have a look in the ".sonar/target/logs/codesniffer.xml" file and check errors that are returned to check if your "<configKey>...</configKey>" tags are correctly set.

Comment: <error line="7" column="77" severity="error" message="Whitespace must be added before and after the assignment operator. Found &quot;]='layout,select_key,pages'&quot;. Expected &quot;] = 'layout,select_key,pages'&quot;" source="TYPO3.WhiteSpace.AssignmentArithmeticAndComparisonSpace"/>
  <error line="9" column="15" severity="error" message="No space found after comma in function call" source="Generic.Functions.FunctionCallArgumentSpacing.NoSpaceAfterComma"/>

Comment: :can yu please tell what is the configkey and how to set this .

Comment: @Fabric-Sonar Team: juz now i have modified rule.xml file and added only one rule in codesniffer.xml am getting the violation but not in dashboard <rule key="TYPO3.Classes.LowercaseClassKeywords.ClassDocComment"
  priority="MAJOR">
  <category name="Maintainability" />
  <name>LowercaseClassKeywords</name>
  <configKey>T_WHITESPACE</configKey>
  <description>@category tag comment incorrectly indented</description>
 </rule>

Comment: IIRC, the value of the "key" attribute (in the "rules.xml" file) should be equal to the value of the "source" attribute that you'll find in the PhpCodesniffer report.

Comment: @Fabric-Sonar Team:in rules.xml a rule with configKey  <configKey>TYPO3.WhiteSpace.DisallowSpaceIndent.http://forge.typo3.org/projects/team-php_codesniffer/wiki/Whitespace#Indent-code</configKey>

in codesniffer.xml   <error line="34" column="3" severity="error" message="Tabs must be used to indent lines; spaces are not allowed" source="TYPO3.WhiteSpace.DisallowSpaceIndent.http://forge.typo3.org/projects/team-php_codesniffer/wiki/Whitespace#Indent-code"/>
But shows nothing in front end .

Answer (score 0):

The rules should be link this only

```
<rule key="TYPO3.Commenting.ValidCommentLineLength.ValidCommentLineLength"
            priority="MAJOR">
            <category name="Maintainability" />
            <name>TYPO3.Commenting.ValidCommentLineLength.ValidCommentLineLength</name>
            <Key>TYPO3.Commenting.ValidCommentLineLength</Key>
            <description>@category</description>
        </rule>
```

Also i have changed 'configKey' to 'Key'

The value of the "key" attribute (in the "rules.xml" file) should be equal to the value of the "source" attribute that you'll find in the PhpCodesniffer report.